# Battlestar Evacuations

Tags: battlestar-galactica, battlestar-galactica-2004

If a Battlestar is critically damaged from say, a battle or an accident, then how can the entire crew of the Battlestar evacuate in a hurry?
Are Battlestars equipped with lifeboats or escape pods?

Answer (score 5):

Battlestars would definitely have had evacuation setup.

1) detailed (and likely drilled) evacuation plans to leave the ship by the flight pods and disaster pods (see number 2 below). This is a military vessel, which means worst-case loss of the ship and thus the order to abandon-ship, and thus evacuation of personnel will be drilled over and over and over until it's second-nature for everyone. (No I don't have a source for this one, but it's common sense. I have a few buddies who have served in the Navy and could verify this practice)

2) Disaster pods that could turn into mini personnel un-powered (meaning no engines, so likely just batteries or finite power of some sort) escape ships, parts of the bigger hull that could be broken away, sealed, and then could serve as a "lifeboat" of sorts, and that could later dock with other Battlestars/Colonial ships. It's actually mentioned that the sick bay on Galactica could become one of these disaster pods if necessary. Tigh actually says he'll issue a couple of these disaster pods to aid civilians on some utility ships after Lee Adama asks him to, back when the fleet was starting to assemble.

Source: https://en.battlestarwikiclone.org/wiki/Disaster_pod